# Creating a loop for inserting data inside the table

Tags: javascript

I have got a simple loop that puts data from a list to the table:

```
      standings.forEach(function(item, i) {
        const rowData = document.createElement("tr");
        const tdData = document.createElement("td");
        const tdData2 = document.createElement("td");
        const tdData3 = document.createElement("td");
        const tdData4 = document.createElement("td");
        const tdData5 = document.createElement("td");
        tbody.appendChild(rowData);
        tdData.textContent = item.position;
        rowData.appendChild(tdData);
        tdData2.textContent = `${item.name} ${item.surname}`;
        rowData.appendChild(tdData2);
        tdData3.textContent = item.data2;
        rowData.appendChild(tdData3);
        tdData4.textContent = item.point;
        rowData.appendChild(tdData4);
        tdData5.textContent = item.fruits;
        rowData.appendChild(tdData5);
      })
```

Anyone knows how I can automate this process? I don't think, that my way is super efficient, so I am looking for another answer.

Comment: consider a web frontend ui framework like react, vue, angular, etc.

Comment: @DanielA.White unfortunately this has to be done in pure js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically break repeating elements down into smaller pieces, and then repeat as needed to make it easier to read. For instance, you are creating a lot of 'td' elements with text inside it, so I would start with something like:

```
function newElementWithText( innerText )
{
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.textContent = innerText;
  return td;
}
```

to handle that part. If you incorporate that solely into your code, you would have:

```
standings.forEach(function(item, i) {
  const rowData = document.createElement("tr");
  rowData.appendChild( 
    newElementWithText(item.position) );
  rowData.appendChild( 
    newElementWithText(`${item.name} ${item.surname}`);
  rowData.appendChild( newElementWithText(item.data2);
  rowData.appendChild( newElementWithText(item.point);
  rowData.appendChild( 
    newElementWithText(item.fruits) );

  tbody.appendChild(rowData);
}
```

This can be made more readable using an array of the data that is needed, and then mapping it into the new td element, and then finally appending it.

```
standings.forEach(function(item, i) {

  const rowData = document.createElement("tr");
  const data = [
    item.position,
    `${item.name} ${item.surname}`,
    item.data2,
    item.point,
    item.fruits
  ];

  //Creates an array of the 'td' elements with text.
  var tdElements = data.map( x => newElementWithText(x) );
  //Iterates over the new array and appends to the rowData.
  tdElements.map( x => rowData.appendChild(x) );

  tbody.appendChild(rowData);
}
```

- Full disclaimer, I have not fully tested this code for syntax errors, but it works in theory.